# How can I convert this date "03/01/2018 12:00 AM" to "2018-03-01" in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using this code to convert a date `03/01/2018 12:00 AM` to `2018-03-01` in C#:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox1.Text.ToString(),
                                         "yyyy-mm-dd",
                                         System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but it throws an exception

> String was not recognized as valid datetime

Comment: You can accept an answer by pressing the tick next to it.

Comment: If this has answered your question, you can press the green tick to the left of the answer, so that people searching in future know which answer solved your problem. If not, you can explain why it is not quite right, so people can help you find the answer.

Comment: If you really want to thank me for my answer, [rather than adding a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), the best way is to press the green tick below the V to the left of my answer.

Comment: You will benefit from accepting an answer, and it costs you nothing. Here is an example showing where the green tick is https://stackoverflow.com/a/49314215/5198140

Comment: Are you up voting my comments by mistake? Please scroll down to my answer and press the tick next to it. Or [edit] your question to explain why none of these answers work for you. Thankyou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This Will Work Like A Charm**

```
       string bs = "03/01/2018 12:00 AM";
       String startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(bs,"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
       Console.WriteLine(startDate);
       // Outputs 2018-03-01
```

*You can verify the code [here](http://rextester.com/YFB12669)*

Comment: Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, and you feed him for a lifetime. Also to point out that this doesn't 'work like a charm' because you've failed to notice from the phrasing of the question that the 03 represents a month, so the ParseExact format should begin "MM/dd", meaning month and day are stored in the wrong places, which you have overcome by altering the format string 'yyyy-mm-dd' given in the question. Those two wrongs don't make a right.

Comment: @Richardissimo I fixed it for OP.

Comment: @Richardissimo i m sorry for that

Comment: No problem. I was just concerned that this answer had had multiple up votes, but wasn't correct. Its all fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

A DateTime represents a particular point in time. ParseExact is a way of turning a string into a DateTime. By saying ParseExact with "yyyy-mm-dd" you are telling it that the string you are giving it begins with a four digit year, which it doesn't. Fix the format string that you are supplying so that the parse works.

Once you have the value in your DateTime variable, you can use ToString("yyyy-mm-dd") to turn that DateTime back into a string.

Comment: @DeepakJangid Given that you want 2018-03-01, you will need "yyyy-MM-dd", rather than the "yyyy-mm-dd" used in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `AM` from your Textbox and edit format string, then your sample code will work.

This line run successfully :

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact("03/01/2018 12:00", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
    string inputDate = "03/01/2018 12:00 AM";
    string outputDate = DateTime.Parse(inputDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Does this work equally well in the US and the UK? Or is it only accurate between the 13th and 31st of the month (inclusive)?