# Unicode to ASCII

Tags: c#, unicode, ascii

I have a Unicode : `¾àÖ‘œ`.

I need to convert this Unicode into ASCII. I tried with the below code,but the output result is incorrect .For the Unicode `'¾'` output answer is 64.

```
String as_pass = "¾àÖ‘œ";

li_passlen = as_pass.Length;

byte[] asciiBytes = new byte[li_passlen];

asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(as_pass);
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: You can’t because none of these are ASCII characters. What is your expected result?

Comment: If i put this Unicode to the online ASCII Converter ,it result the correct ASCII code ,but i cant use this with c#

Comment: not the one i just tried

Comment: But what is the relation between ¾ and ascii 64? I cannot see any.

Comment: The correct ASCII code for the '¾' is '190', the above code output ASCII code is 64

Comment: Ok i think I see what you mean. You need this: `asciiBytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(as_pass);`

Comment: Thanks a lot ,it output the correct answer .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are refering to so called "extended" ascii, which is group of encodings extending regular 7-bit ascii by 1 bit (sometimes even more). One such encoding is iso-8859-1, which seems to be the one you need. So to get result you expect, do:

```
asciiBytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(as_pass);
```

Comment: @Yasitha To drive the point home, people often say ASCII when they don't mean the ASCII character set or its one character encoding. Saying "Extended ASCII" is even less informative because when dealing with character encodings exactly one is used and, to use it, which it is has to be known by all parties. So, whoever you give those bytes to, pass along the essential information that they are iso-8859-1 encoded text.